# How does PortMap forwards the port?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I installed PortMap on my Mac - I was sure it would do port forwarding on my local IP address. I wanted to forward port 8001 to 8000. So, when going to 192.168.1.105:8001, I would end up at 192.168.1.106:8000.
Here's my setting (I covered my public IP):
[image]

It turned out that my rule does not forward ports on local IP. However, it does forward on public IP of my network! How is that possible?

When someone tries to access my network's public IP, he gets to the router. I don't understand how one of computers on my network is able to dictate what will happen next. How does my router know that it should route the traffic to the specific computer where I set this port forwarding?

Comment: Looks like it uses [UPNP NAT traversal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) from the screenshot

Comment: Interesting, thanks. So it seems that my router enables the devices in its network to configure port forwarding - which is a bit scary actually.

Comment: It's a nice feature for your average consumer so they dont have to deal with setting up forwards for their Playstations, Xboxes, Bittorrents, etc.  Some routers have a setting for this so you can disable it and do your forwards manually if preferred.